# Let $P$ be an orthogonal matrix with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ an eigenvalue of $P$, show that $\lambda = \pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried using some properties of matrix multiplication to try to get to an answer, but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: What are the possible values of $|\lambda|$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You may know that if $P$ is an orthgonal matrix, then $\left\|Px \right\| = \left\|x \right\|$.

On the other hand, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $P$, you have $Px = \lambda x$.

Can you add the pieces together?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a matrix $O$ is orthogonal iff $O^{-1}= O^t$.
If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $O$, then $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue for $O^t$. Which are the eigenvalues for $O^{-1}$?